# Group by in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

In my table I have event and date(as columns name). Events can repeat.

I want to know the count of each event in the table.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you want to count events datewise?

Comment: no need on datewise just count of each events

Comment: It's not that clear what you want. Do you need to counts event by date or am I missing something?

Comment: What I can understand from your question is that you want to find count of events based on names which can be done as by selecting appropriate any other additional columns of your choice 
    Event.find(:all, :select => "count(events.*)", :group => "ëvents.name")

Answer (score 1):

`Event.all.count` should do it

Comment: i don't want total count. I need each event count. so many events presents in table events are repeatable. For example my fist event as "The Temper Trap" and 10th event as"The Temper Trap" and my 62th event as "The Temper Trap" means i want to found the count of "The Temper Trap" event

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column in your Event model is "event". (otherwise replace "event" by whatever you want to group by

```
x = Event.group(:event).count
```

The above returns you a hash keyed on the event and the value representing the count

```
puts x["The Temper Trap"] # => 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map:

```
Event.map { |event| event.count }
```

Or a loop:

```
For event in Event
  event.count
end
```

Or iteration:

```
Event.each do |event|
  event.count
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Event.count(:group => :name)
```

It should return an ordered hash of event-name vs count.